# How do I make MythTV remember its audio settings?

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, audio, alsa, mythtv, pulse-audio

I'm running MythTV on Ubuntu 9.10 and I'm having problems with audio settings. I have one combined backend/frontend and two other frontends. One of the frontends has two audio outputs: the one built in to the motherboard and a USB box. Whenever I restart this PC, MythTV seems to lose the audio settings and I have to play around with them (i.e. alsa:plughw:x,y) to get it to work again. It's almost like it's pulling them from the database on the backend. (I need to check if the incorrect setting it keeps getting is the one used on the backend/frontend combo.)

In general, is there an easy way to avoid having to mess with my alsa configuration to get this to work properly? I tried setting up PulseAudio to work via alsa, but that wasn't successful either...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

They do get their settings from the backend! :) Is it possible that you have two machines with the same hostname? That might make this happen because settings are stored on a per-hostname basis. You can simply use phpmyadmin and dig around the mysql table to look at the settings manually.

One thing to try to see if it fixes it is to simply change the hostname, regardless if you have duplicates or not:
http://www.mythtv.org/docs/mythtv-HOWTO-23.html